# Alterar CSS de elemento quando menu estiver fixado ao topo

Tags: css, html5, twitter-bootstrap

Estou usando a classe sticky-top do bootstrap, para fixar o menu ao topo. Porém gostaria que enquanto o menu não estivesse fixado, não aparecesse o ícone.

Me refiro a `.menu-principal img`, gostaria que quando o menu se fixasse ao topo a opacidade de `.menu-principal img` mudasse de 0 para 1. Estou usando jquery, bootstrap e o plugin visibility. Sou iniciante em desenvolvimento web.

Esse é o menu:

```
 <nav class=" sticky-top menu-principal navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
    <div class="container d-flex justify-content-between">
      <span style="display: block; width: 56px;"></span>
        <a class="navbar-brand m-0" href="index.html">
            <img src="icons/logo-simples.svg" alt="logotipo simplificado">
        </a>

        <button class="navbar-toggler float-right" data-toggle="collapse" 
              data-target="#navbarMenu">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarMenu">
          <div class="navbar-nav">
            <a href="index.html" class="nav-item nav-link active"> Home</a>
            <a href="portfolio.html" class="nav-item nav-link"> Portfolio</a>
            <a href="historia.html" class="nav-item nav-link"> História</a>
            <a href="sobre.html" class="nav-item nav-link"> Sobre</a>
          </div>
        </div>
     </div> 
</nav>
```

Esse é o CSS do Menu

```
.menu-principal {
background-color: #1C4F6E;
font-weight: bold;
letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.menu-principal .navbar-nav a {
  color: #FFF !important;
  margin-left: 6px;
  margin-right: 6px;
}

.menu-principal .navbar-nav .active {
   color: #FF9127 !important;
}

.menu-principal .navbar-nav a:hover {
  color: #FF9127 !important;
 }

.menu-principal img {
   opacity: 0;
    height: 60px;
}


 @media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
   .menu-principal img {
       height: 50px;
    }

.menu-principal .navbar-nav a {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
}

.navbar-nav {
    padding: 10px;
}

.navbar-toggler {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.menu-principal .container {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como vc falou que tem jQuery no projeto aqui vai uma resposta. Mas te adiante que só com CSS não da para fazer pq CSS não detecta evento de Scroll na janela dessa forma...

A ideia é usar os métodos `fadeIn` e `fadeOut` do jQuery para mostra a imagem ou não caso o `scroll` seja maior que a altura da `navbar`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código da imagem acima.

`OBS:` Sua `navbar` tem alguns problemas, não sei se ela está de acordo com a documentação, mas em modo mobile quando vc abre ela não está ficando legal, isso não é problema do código que eu fiz, foi outro CSS ou alguma coisa que vc não colocou no código...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Page Title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/css/all.min.css" />
<style>
    .menu-principal {
        background-color: #1C4F6E;
        font-weight: bold;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
        height: 76px;
    }

    .menu-principal .navbar-nav a {
        color: #FFF !important;
        margin-left: 6px;
        margin-right: 6px;
    }

    .menu-principal .navbar-nav .active {
        color: #FF9127 !important;
    }

    .menu-principal .navbar-nav a:hover {
        color: #FF9127 !important;
    }

    .menu-principal img {
        height: 60px;
    }

    .navbar-brand {
        display: none;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
        .menu-principal img {
            height: 50px;
        }

        .menu-principal .navbar-nav a {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 10px;
        }

        .navbar-nav {
            padding: 10px;
        }

        .navbar-toggler {
            margin-top: 10px;
        }

        .menu-principal .container {
            display: inline-block;
            text-align: center;
        }
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>

    <nav class=" sticky-top menu-principal navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
        <div class="container d-flex justify-content-between">
            <span style="display: block; width: 56px;"></span>
            <a class="navbar-brand m-0" href="index.html">
                <img src="https://placecage.com/16/16"  alt="logotipo simplificado">
            </a>

            <button class="navbar-toggler float-right" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarMenu">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarMenu">
                <div class="navbar-nav">
                    <a href="index.html" class="nav-item nav-link active"> Home</a>
                    <a href="portfolio.html" class="nav-item nav-link"> Portfolio</a>
                    <a href="historia.html" class="nav-item nav-link"> História</a>
                    <a href="sobre.html" class="nav-item nav-link"> Sobre</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col" style="height: 200vh">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Deserunt quia in provident praesentium quam numquam excepturi doloribus nobis deleniti, quaerat iste labore accusantium ea aspernatur asperiores beatae aperiam quas velit accusamus? Aliquam, quo tempore vel accusantium facere temporibus quis vero officiis dolor magni porro ipsam reprehenderit incidunt repudiandae, error cumque totam odio nam? Inventore iure placeat tempora facilis molestias obcaecati voluptates nam nihil nobis, facere nesciunt qui quibusdam sit sed dignissimos libero non, explicabo rerum provident dolorum voluptatibus asperiores? Rerum alias nam necessitatibus laudantium praesentium corporis, blanditiis voluptas ipsa? Optio accusamus deleniti reprehenderit velit aliquid nesciunt nobis ducimus delectus magni.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script>

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scroll >= 76) { // altura da sua navbar
            $(".navbar-brand").fadeIn();
        } else {
            $(".navbar-brand").fadeOut();
        }
    });

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Valeu, era exatamente isso que eu estava querendo

Comment: @Erulos tranqilo jovem, que bom que ajudou ai, se vc não quiser usar o `fadeIn / Out` vc pode adicionar ou remover uma classe, ai vc cria a classe que quer remover/adcionar e no Script vc troca onde está `fadeIn` por `addClass` e `removeClass`